# Android Eclipse Plugin Too Slow

Tags: android, performance, eclipse-plugin

I'm currently on a Windows 7 box with 1.83GHz processor and 1 GB RAM. I used be able to use all applications with no speed issues. I recently installed Android Plugin in Eclipse Helios and now Eclipse has slowed down badly. Running projects/creating projects/saving code changes all takes 3-4 minutes to happen. When the emulator is launched, it takes a good 10 minutes to be able to use my app. What is causing Eclipse to slow down ?? Wasting a lot of time on this. Please help.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: 1GB of RAM is too little for Windows 7 alone, IMHO, let alone for actually running *programs* on it.

Comment: "I used be able to use all applications with no speed issues" What does all mean, because I highly doubt that. It should be obvious that running an emulated OS requires some more system resources than just using windows media player. Just as some other guys already pointed out your hardware is not even the best for Windows 7 so how do you think your hardware is enough to emulate another os? Sure the emulater isn't even running that smooth on most machines but srsly the min. system requiremnts http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/system-requirements should indicate your problem.

Comment: Thanks guys... :) will upgrade my RAM... Guess I have no other option...

Answer (score 3):

Your system should be running on the edge of the limit when you have Eclipse and the Emulator running. If possible work on a device or check the CPU/RAM usage while working. You should be able to see where the bottleneck is.

If you have Windows XP somewhere, I strongly recommend to switch back to XP...

Answer (score 3):

Usually when your using programming envionments such as eclipse it is very taxing on your computer. The emulator taking up to ten mins to run is not shocking. I also had the same problem but if you have an android device you can use it to test your programs (its almost instant compared to the emulator.)