# Eclipse is too slow

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Eclipse Plugin Too Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243737/android-eclipse-plugin-too-slow)

I'm an Android programmer and when programming with eclipse if the program is very large, whenever I change the content of Android XML Files, the eclipse taking a very long time to refactor, I want to know if any other IDE or language can use for android developing and is faster than eclipse, or if such method that let the eclipse go faster exist? Thanks

By the way, my machine is win7 with AMD 640, 8G memory, 1T hard disk and HD6770 Video Card. So I don't think that it is because of my slow machine that makes the eclipse slow. And the eclipse IDE running show only when the program is large enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't tell about other IDEs, but you can turn off autobuild (Project -> Build automatically). But this way you will have to rebuild project manually.

Comment: Alternatives for developement if you want http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/ and http://developer.motorola.com/tools/motodevstudio/

Comment: That doesn't speed up compilation.  Even if you want to build manually...